# Present Perfect with "yesterday"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, tenses

Is it possible to say "I've told you that yesterday" if the meaning is "you should already know it", thus being directly related to the present? The moment in the past is not the important part, but rather the fact that I DID tell you and yet you don't know it.

Comment: it would be more natural to use the simple past

Comment: As Toothrot says ‘I told you that yesterday’ is idiomatic. Also if emphasised or indignant, you might say ‘I already told you that yesterday!’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present Perfect has strong connection with Present time. It is also called *Before present*. In the spotlight of Present perfect is not the time of action but it is result. 
Yesterday indicates Past time. It shows an action as a fact not a result. Only Past tenses can be used in this case.

Comment: Clearly some time references are valid in conjunction with the present perfect; e.g., "I have traveled to country *X* recently, so I'm not allowed to donate blood now."  Is there a rule for distinguishing terms for "past time" that can be used with the present perfect from those that can't?

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, if what you said  yesterday has some kind of relevance *to you* in the present, then I suppose the Present Perfect would make sense, although it's grammatically incorrect as "yesterday" refers to a past time period.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).